# Change in optics related experiments by changing optical density of lenses

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

For most of the time experiments concerning optics have been done in either air or vacuum as necessary. All the lenses we have used have their optical density more than that of the experimenting medium. But if we use a lens/ or a slab or anything which has optical density less than that of the experimenting medium how would image formation, focal length and other characteristics of length change if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

The focal length would change sign, so you'd need a concave lens where you'd had a convex lens before, and vice versa.